# Is there a way to plot a randomwalk process using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

So my aim is to compare the movement of the random walk process with stock prices movement.
I created a random walk process and plotted that as follows
`P1<-RW(100,10,0,0.0004) plot(P2, main="Random Walk without Drift",  xlab="index(",ylab="Price", ylim=c(9.7,10.3), typ='l', col="blue")`
and it worked.
But is it possible to use `ggplot` instead of  `plot`

Comment: Create a data.frame with `x=seq_along(P2)` and `y=P2`. Then it's a matter of plotting points or lines or both. Can you post the code of function `RW` or where (package) to find the function?

Comment: FYI, you create `P1` and use `P2` ... not sure if you're doing something else that is relevant to the issue.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks for this. The function   RW is in quantmod package

Comment: @r2evans thanks for flagging this, actually I create and use both, ( they are both random walk processes with and without a drift).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base graphics, when you do `plot(x)` (and no `y` component), several things go on under the hood. Notably, though, is that it calls `xy.coords(x, y)`, which eventually does ...

```r
        else {
            if (is.factor(x)) 
                x <- as.numeric(x)
            if (setLab) 
                xlab <- "Index"
            y <- x
            x <- seq_along(x)
        }
```

which is the clue into how to get `ggplot2` to do effectively the same thing: by assign the values to `y` and creating a sequence into `x`.

```r
set.seed(42)
P1 <- cumsum(rnorm(1000))
plot(P1, type = "l")
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = seq_along(P1), y = P1)) + geom_line()
```

or in a "formalized" `data.frame`:

```r
dat <- data.frame(x = seq_along(P1), y = P1)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line()
```

[image: base R random walk]

[image: ggplot2, same random walk]

Comment: I am trying to limit my random walk process to positive values as follows   set.seed(42)
  P1 <- cumsum(rnorm(1111))
  P1(P1>=0) = resample , but  R is giving me the following error message "rror: unexpected input in "  %P1(P1>=0) = resample" any idea why ?

Comment: `P1(P1>=0)` is only meaningful if there exists somewhere a *function* named `P1` (as well as a function named `\`P1<-\``, since the code appear to assign to it with `=` immed afterwards), and a *variable* (`numeric` or `integer`) named `P1`, which seems unlikely. Do you mean to use `P1[P1>=0] <- resample` where resample is a length-1 number? Or do you mean `resample <- P1[P1>=0]`?